# NestedScrollView not working with MotionLayout

Tags: android, scrollview, android-motionlayout

Why Google, why do you have to make things sooo difficult???

Here is my situation, I am using Google's code for MotionLayoutsCodeLab as my base.

I added a NestedScrollView to my layout and what was working perfectly before no longer works. The motion layout went from being smooth and effortless to laggy and none responsive. I need to have the NestedScrollView as part of my requirement so removing it is not an option.

Here is my simple view

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white">

    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
            android:orientation="vertical">

        <com.google.samples.motionlayoutcodelab.FakeSliderView
            android:id="@+id/accessSlider"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Here is my View.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout>
<androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/motionLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="50dp"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    app:layoutDescription="@xml/activity_step1_scene">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/slider_bg1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_open_door_gray" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/slider_bg2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_open_door_done" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/label_swipe_to_open"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Swipe to Open"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#9191A1" />

    <com.google.samples.motionlayoutcodelab.LockSliderImageView
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="49dp"
        android:translationZ="2dp"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout>
</layout>
```

Here is my scene xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<MotionScene xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:motion="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <Transition
        motion:constraintSetEnd="@+id/end"
        motion:constraintSetStart="@+id/start"
        motion:duration="1500"
        motion:motionInterpolator="linear">
        <OnSwipe
            motion:dragDirection="dragRight"
            motion:dragThreshold="15"
            motion:maxAcceleration="10"
            motion:onTouchUp="decelerateAndComplete"
            motion:touchAnchorId="@id/button"
            motion:touchAnchorSide="right" />
    </Transition>

    <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/start">
        <Constraint
            android:id="@id/button"
            android:layout_width="95dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:visibility="visible"
            motion:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
        </Constraint>

        <Constraint
            android:id="@id/slider_bg1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            motion:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">
        </Constraint>

        <Constraint
            android:id="@id/slider_bg2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            motion:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">
        </Constraint>
        <Constraint
            android:id="@+id/label_swipe_to_open"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            motion:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">
            <CustomAttribute
                motion:attributeName="alpha"
                motion:customFloatValue="1.0" />
        </Constraint>

    </ConstraintSet>

    <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/end">
        <Constraint
            android:id="@id/button"
            android:layout_width="95dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            motion:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
        </Constraint>

        <Constraint
            android:id="@id/slider_bg1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            motion:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">
        </Constraint>

        <Constraint
            android:id="@id/slider_bg2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            motion:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">
        </Constraint>

        <Constraint
            android:id="@id/label_swipe_to_open"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            motion:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">
            <CustomAttribute
                motion:attributeName="alpha"
                motion:customFloatValue="0.0" />
        </Constraint>

    </ConstraintSet>

</MotionScene>
```

This is what it looks like.
[image]

I have come across several SO articles that recommend using android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants" but unfortunatly it also does not work.

So my question is: How can I get my MotionLayout to work with a NestedScrollView.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I have almost an identical problem

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add `nestedScrollFlags="disableScroll"` to the on swipe
This will tell onSwipe to ignore the nestedScrollFlags.

```
 <OnSwipe
        motion:nestedScrollFlags="disableScroll"
        motion:dragDirection="dragRight"
        motion:dragThreshold="15"
        motion:maxAcceleration="10"
        motion:onTouchUp="decelerateAndComplete"
        motion:touchAnchorId="@id/button"
        motion:touchAnchorSide="right" />
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion unfortunately no luck.  The slide is still very laggy or janky not sure how to best describe it.

Comment: Post a video of it.